# A platform for Java, Scala, Groovy and jRuby would be implemented in what language?

Tags: java, scala, grails, groovy, jruby

As an experiment I am working on a small platform for Java applications (client server, P2P etc.) which I would like to be able to use from both Java and Scala. And possibly also from Groovy, jRuby etc.

I know that Scala can call easily into Java, but that Java cannot as easily call back into Scala. I don't know how this is working in jRuby and Groovy.

My initial thought was to implement the platform in Java, and then see if I could make it available to other languages. However, the platform may include starting threads which call components that implement certain Java interfaces. Would it be possible to pass e.g. a factory implemented in Scala, but which implements a Java interface, to a Java component and have that Java component call the Scala factory?

What are your recommendations in general for implementing such a cross language platform?

Comment: The way you describe (java core + per-language api) is the way vert.x does it

Comment: Perhaps you could make your application language neutral, as a working HTTP (or other universal protocol) server. Then anything imaginable could work with it, maybe using JSON for example so the objects are fairly universal at that point.

Comment: It will have an HTTP / TCP interface. But you need to run components inside the platform - like servlets or PHP pages. stuff like that.

Answer (score 3):

I am by no means an expert and have never done such a cross-language project (just minor Java/Scala).

But I would suggest implementing it in the language:

- you know best
- makes you most productive
- ensures the most maintainability

In my case it would be Scala.

So what I would do is define the API in the form of **Java interfaces**, which I would then implement in Scala (probably I would need to convert Scala/Java collections back-and-forth, but that would be an implementation detail).

That way you make sure that other JVM languages can interact with your API, and you implement it in whatever language you are best.

Comment: So, it would make sense to code the platform in Java, and then later see how to make it available from other languages, right?

Comment: There **are** examples of such projects -- Akka and Storm -- and yes, both are done as *java-first* project (so scala and clojure code implement java interfaces).

Comment: If you feel so inclined of course you can code the platform entirely in Java. But as I stated I don't think this is a necessary requirement. It would be enough if you present a Java-compatible API to the outside world. I would implement Java interfaces in whatever language I would be implementing it. I think the Play framework is also implemented in Scala, but presents Java APIs.

Comment: Additionally, it could be a good idea to have test-coverage for API usage in the different JVM languages; but it might be an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Java can call Scala as easy at the other way around,
With eclipse you need to install 'Scala IDE' from the 'eclipse market place'
and configure the compiler to 'Scala Then Java' option in Properties->'Scala Compiler'-> 'Build Manager'-> compileorder.

P.s. you also need to add Scala nature to the project.

Comment: So, it would make sense to code the platform in Java, and then later see how to make it available from other languages, right?

Comment: Yes! it is more then makes sense. Java can be merged into all other languages such as jPython, Scala, Groovy etc. since they all acknowledge the value of Java's packages.

Answer (score 1):

`Would it be possible to pass e.g. a factory implemented in Scala, but which implements a Java interface, to a Java component and have that Java component call the Scala factory?`

Even if it were so, switching to Scala would not solve the problem, as then jRuby would have even more problems to access that component.

Actually, all listed languages declare interoperability with Java, but not with other languages. So first design goal is, your platform should be Java-compatible in all its API, though some components could be written in other languages - but so that it is cannot be seen by API users. The easiest way to make it so is to write all in Java. Besides, I recommend Java because features of "more advanced" languages has their reverse side - one innocent-looking line of code can consume enormous amounts of CPU time or memory.

Comment: So she/he should write it C, because one innocent-looking line of code can consume enormous amounts of CPU time or memory? (And make it available with thin java wrapper?)